# Find primitive $F$ of $f(x) = e^x-2x$ that satisfies $F(1) = e -3$

Tags: calculus, functions, indefinite-integrals

$$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R , f(x)=e^x-2x$$

Find primitive $F$ of $f(x)$ that satisfies $F(1) = e-3$.

$$F(x)=e^x-x^2+C$$

I am really confused by the subject of primitives, I very rarely get exercise that refer them. How should I approach this exercise? The way I understand it, a continuous function has infinitely many primitives that differ by a constant? Does this exercise sum up to finding the value of $C$ that satisfy the equation $F(1)=e-3$ then ?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there: We want $e -3 = F(1) = e^1 - 1^2 + C$. Solve for $C$.

Comment: That was not the hard part, I needed someone to clarify it for me. There is a similar exercise that asks the same thing. Find primitive $F$ of $f(x)=xe^x$ such that $F(1)=0$. $F(x) = e^x(x-1)$. The equation $F(1)=0$ is equivalent to $0=0$. What do I do in this case? Does it mean that ALL the primitives satisfy the condition?

Comment: @RaduGabriel, ask a separate question or edit and improve your question.

Comment: It seems quite clear to me, In short words it asks "Does this kind of exercises (find primitive of f such that $F(a)=b$) sum up to solving for $C$? And it has an example attached to it too, I could have added this other example but it would've just made the question too long then and it's just another example, it doesn't add that much more.

Comment: A "primitive" for function f(x) is an anti-derivative.  Finding a primitive "sums up to solving for C" on **after** you have done the integration, which is typically the hard part!